Null data return from Infura API by using "eth_getLogs" method
I want to get the ETH transfer volume from wallet address via Infura API on Postman.
But there is NULL data inside the API result.
I expected there is data in result, but nothing now.
My URL:
POST method
https://mainnet.infura.io/v3/{{my_infura_project_key}}

My API Request body:
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "eth_getLogs",
  "params": [{
    "fromBlock": "0x13A80FC",
    "toBlock": "0x13A7E2B",
    "address": "0xd2674dA94285660c9b2353131bef2d8211369A4B"
  }],
  "id": 1
}

The Response:
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 1,
    "result": []
}


"0xd2674dA94285660c9b2353131bef2d8211369A4B" is not a contract, that's why there are no events.
In any case, you can't look at ETH transfers this way since they don't emit a log. The best way is probably still using etherscan API or something similar.
